# What are the ways I can use a map to scale or rotate the map visually while having a pattern over it?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps

I want to use a map for more things that just watch at it. (By map I mean Google Maps or OpenStreetMap or another if necessary)

What I want to do is, once I have a location I want to move a drawing over it.  Be able to rotate or scale the map visually. Is this possible.

If possible I would like to do it visually. If not, programmatically is ok too.

For example, I locate the Shibuya crossing and the Roppongi crossing in Tokyo in the map. I draw a horizontal line of two points and want to scale and rotate the map so that this line corresponds to these two locations

Comment: As noted in the comments of the Question you deleted, this may not work as you expect, because "scale and rotate" isn't likely to be enough, especially working with a Web Mercator map.